# OpenSSL and Rand_bytes

Tags: macos, gcc, openssl

My question is in regards to using OpenSSL on Mac via GCC.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <openssl/rand.h>

    int main()
    {
     unsigned char key[128];
     Rand_bytes(key,128);
     return 0;
    }
```

I have the following code, that I am trying to compile with GCC. Here is what I enter into the command line

```
    gcc -o ossl ossl.c -lcrypto -lssl
```

However I get the following error.

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>    "_Rand_bytes", referenced from:
>        _main in cc2hf0Ij.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I am not experienced when it comes to using openssl. Why am I receiving `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64`?

Comment: It sounds like you need a different version of openssl. It looks to me like that "undefined symbol" linker error means that the linked openssl library does not define the "Rand_bytes" function.

Comment: thanks I think you are right...I think on the mac it got replaced with apple's version of crypto. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> int main()
> {
>     unsigned char key[128];
>     Rand_bytes(key,128);
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

Try `RAND_bytes`:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char key[128];
    int rc = RAND_bytes(key,sizeof(key));
    if(rc != 1)
        /* Handle failure */

    ...
    OPENSSL_cleanse(key,sizeof(key));
    return 0;
}
```

The OpenSSL docs are at [`RAND_bytes(3)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RAND_bytes.html).